# get string inside quotes with sed

Tags: sed

I have a file with text like these:

```
"id":1519539,"description":"xxxxxxxx","severity":"yyy","pasahelpdesk":null,"subSource":"","dateReception":{"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/France","timestamp":1549493320},"sg_datatables_editable":[
false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]},{
"id":1519540,"description":"xxxxxxxx","severity":"yyy","pasahelpdesk":null,"subSource":"","dateReception":{"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/France","timestamp":1549493340},"sg_datatables_editable":[
false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]},{
```

I'm trying to get value of timestamp. I'm trying with:

```
sed "s/.*timestamp\":\(.*\).*$/\1/g"
```

but it gives the value of timestamp but also all values until end of the line:

```
1549493320},"sg_datatables_editable":[
false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]},{
1549493340},"sg_datatables_editable":[
false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]},{
```

How can I get only:

```
1549493320
1549493340
```

Comment: If this is json formatted, then I suggest you use a json parser, e.g. jq or jtc

Answer (score 1):

You can do it sample with `awk` like this

```
awk -F'[,:}]' '{print $16}' input_file
```

Also if your file is in JSON format you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: I woud like to extract with sed. Not always is in 16th position, and is not a jq file

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. You print non-matching lines
2. You match too much

The first can be solved with using `-n` and `p`, the second by narrowing down what you match, e.g. with ERE:

```
sed -nE 's/.*"timestamp":([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: thanks! it works? But I'm trying to understand your solution. Why "-nE" modifier, why you not use character substituion mask like \(xxxxxx\) to use then \1

Comment: The command that I was using is : sed "s/.*timestamp\":\(.*\)}.*/\1/g" and it gives timestamp value but also the values until the end of the line

Comment: @user650034:  I suggest you look `-n` and `-E` up in the manual

Comment: Do you kwno one manual sed specified?

Comment: @user650034: it should be installed with send so running `man sed` would work. Otherwise put it into Google, that works as well

Comment: I don't see -E in man sed

Comment: @user650034: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3139925/1331399